# Golang channel do not close

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I dont get it, why the channel is not closing.
I use `Waitgroup` to explicitly wait and close the channel after it...but th programm isnt exiting.
Thank you for your help

( https://play.golang.org/p/lto2DytWH13 )

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    links := []string{
        "http://google.com",
        "http://facebook.com",
        "http://stackoverflow.com",
        "http://golang.org",
        "http://amazon.com",
    }
    wg.Add(len(links))
    c := make(chan string)

    for _, link := range links {
        go checkLink(link, c, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    close(c)
    for u := range c {
        fmt.Println(u)
    }
}

func checkLink(link string, c chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    _, err := http.Get(link)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(link, "might be down!")
        c <- link
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(link, "is up!")
    c <- link
    wg.Done()
}
```

Comment: The go routines are blocked sending to the channel, as it is unbuffered and no other go routine is receiving.

Comment: ok, I add c := make(chan string, len(links)) to make it async. do you have a bette approach for me? but thank you very much

Comment: That does not make it async. It makes it buffered, which is entirely different.

Comment: The better approach would probably be to use a separate goroutine to read from the channel.

Comment: thank you @Flimzy, I looked into this resource where the author called it async. but my englisch is abd: https://guzalexander.com/2013/12/06/golang-channels-tutorial.html

Comment: The author is wrong. He says "These channels are called asynchronous." That's complete bunk. No channels in Go are ever called async. Channels are only data structures. They don't do processing, so they are neither sync nor async.

Comment: @Flimzy thank you very much for the explanation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the problems with your program:

- When a goroutine successfully reads the link, it prints the `is up!` message, and starts waiting to write the channel. The main goroutine waits for all goroutines to exit, then closes the channel and reads from it. At this point, all goroutines are asleep.
- You are closing the channel, and reading from it. That will immediately return the zero value, i.e. ""
- Your goroutines will return without calling `wg.Done()` if reading from the link fails.

To fix, use:

```
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(c)
    }()
```